# Razor Pages: use one model as a variable for another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am designing a web application that is to keep an IT asset register. I have one model for End Users and one model for Devices. I am trying to use the End User model as a variable for the Device model. Currently, my code for the user variable in the Device class looks like this:

```
[BindProperty]
[Display(Name = "Current User")]
public virtual User CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

When I originally created the CRUD pages for the Device class, it did not add any fields for adding or editing the user variable. The point I am trying to reach is to have a field on the Device's Create page where I can add a User object from the list of Users in my database.
Hope somebody can help, I can supply more code if my description is unclear

Comment: You can pass selected `CurrentUser.UserId` from View to Controller,and get `User CurrentUser` by `CurrentUser.UserId` from database in Controller.And then save `Device` to database.

Comment: @YiyiYou Is there a way that I can do this by having a field on the Create page where I type a user's name and it will search the users currently in my database?

Comment: I'm afraid you could only do it in back end.